# Overflow makes text low resolution

Tags: css

When I style my element with `overflow: auto`, the text becomes blurry.
Why does this happen and how do I prevent it from happening?

[Without `overflow: auto`]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPDLJ.png)

[With `overflow: auto`:]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmpcn.png)

I have tried changing `font-smoothing`, `-webkit-font-smoothing:`

Comment: We'd need a reproduceable example to be able to debug this, and even then, there's a good chance it's device-specific so as many details as you can provide would be useful.

Comment: Please paste in your css and html code